# Debug DLL's under Windows with GDB

Tags: c++, c, debugging, dll, gdb

I have some project consisting of a couple of DLL's which have been compiled with MinGW with debug information, and another project with EXE target which uses these DLLs (compiled with MinGW too).

The problem is, I need to put breakpoints on functions inside those DLLs, but GDB, although sets them, just silently ignores them at runtime. Stepping into them (with 's' key) just skips them over (like with an 'n' key). How can I get inside those DLLs? Maybe there's some option I should specify to GDB? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you add a C or C++ tag, you might get more views.

Comment: Are you adding the breakpoints in the DLL code before or after you start running the program?

Comment: I've tried both ways -- results are the same

Comment: Andy: Show us the command-line you use to compile.  The simplest answer will be if you are missing a needed option.

Comment: "DLL project" is actually build of VLC media player. Here's compilation (*.c => *.o): http://paste.org/pastebin/view/9900. Here's linking (*.o => *.dll, though I not sure first line actually matters): http://paste.org/pastebin/view/9901. As I see, there's -O2, despite the fact I compile it in debug flavour and -g is there. I'll try to recompile it with -O0, as user fnieto recommended below. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you are compiling with [gcc optimization level](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.1/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) flag setted to 0 ( -O0 ).

Comment: Well, this seemed to have desired effect. Though it showed some new unexpected crashes inside VLC :(

Comment: That has nothing to do with the question. At least, now you can debug them.